# Flutter my navigation bar is showing on top

Tags: flutter

I am building an app I need to use a navigation bar so I have following some tutorial to get this type of bar. All things are working fine but the use is the bar is not showing on the bottom its showing on a Top of the page.

MY code

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: Height * 0.1,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("images/nav.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    isDrawerOpen
                        ? Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  xOffset = 0;
                                  yOffset = 0;
                                  scaleFactor = 1;
                                  isDrawerOpen = false;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                height: Height * 0.03,
                                width: Width * 0.06,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: AssetImage("images/ross.png"),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        : Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  xOffset = 280;
                                  yOffset = 150;
                                  scaleFactor = 0.6;
                                  isDrawerOpen = true;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                height: Height * 0.03,
                                width: Width * 0.06,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: AssetImage("images/ic.png"),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                    Container(
                      width: Width * 0.25,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage("images/logo.png"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: Height * 0.03,
                          width: Width * 0.06,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage("images/i2.png"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: Width * 0.04,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: Height * 0.03,
                          width: Width * 0.06,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage("images/i1.png"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: Width * 0.06,
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Home
                    ? Container(
                        height: Height * 0.9,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Hi, this is home page",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    : Container(),
                bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Favorite
                    ? Container(
                        height: Height * 0.9,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Hi, this is favorite page",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    : Container(),
                bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Search
                    ? Container(
                        height: Height * 0.9,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Hi, this is search page",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    : Container(),
                bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Account
                    ? Container(
                        height: Height * 0.9,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Hi, this is account page",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    : Container(),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24, bottom: 30),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        BottomBar(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Home;
                              });
                            },
                            bottomIcons:
                                bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Home ? true : false,
                            icons: EvaIcons.home,
                            text: "Home"),
                        BottomBar(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Favorite;
                              });
                            },
                            bottomIcons: bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Favorite
                                ? true
                                : false,
                            icons: EvaIcons.heartOutline,
                            text: "Favorite"),
                        BottomBar(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Search;
                              });
                            },
                            bottomIcons: bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Search
                                ? true
                                : false,
                            icons: EvaIcons.search,
                            text: "Search"),
                        BottomBar(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Account;
                              });
                            },
                            bottomIcons: bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Account
                                ? true
                                : false,
                            icons: EvaIcons.personOutline,
                            text: "Account"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )

            // Container(
            //   padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20,vertical: 15),
            //   margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30,horizontal: 20),
            //   decoration: BoxDecoration(
            //     color: Colors.white,
            //     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
            //   ),
            //   child: Row(
            //     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            //     children: [
            //       Icon(Icons.search),
            //       Text('Search pet to adopt'),
            //       Icon(Icons.settings)
            //
            //     ],
            //   ),
            // ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

[image]

You can see in image bar is showing on a top of page. I need to show it in bottom of page

Comment: did you want to add [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)?

Comment: already added but its showing on to not on bottom

Comment: [did you try this?](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this.

basically put your widget in `Scaffold` and pass `bottomNavigationBar:YourBottomBar()` widget. i have fixed it.

```
return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          BottomBar(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Home;
                });
              },
              bottomIcons:
              bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Home ? true : false,
              icons: EvaIcons.home,
              text: "Home"),
          BottomBar(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Favorite;
                });
              },
              bottomIcons: bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Favorite
                  ? true
                  : false,
              icons: EvaIcons.heartOutline,
              text: "Favorite"),
          BottomBar(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Search;
                });
              },
              bottomIcons: bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Search
                  ? true
                  : false,
              icons: EvaIcons.search,
              text: "Search"),
          BottomBar(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Account;
                });
              },
              bottomIcons: bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Account
                  ? true
                  : false,
              icons: EvaIcons.personOutline,
              text: "Account"),
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: Height * 0.1,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("images/nav.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    isDrawerOpen
                        ? Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            xOffset = 0;
                            yOffset = 0;
                            scaleFactor = 1;
                            isDrawerOpen = false;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          height: Height * 0.03,
                          width: Width * 0.06,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage("images/ross.png"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                        : Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            xOffset = 280;
                            yOffset = 150;
                            scaleFactor = 0.6;
                            isDrawerOpen = true;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          height: Height * 0.03,
                          width: Width * 0.06,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage("images/ic.png"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: Width * 0.25,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage("images/logo.png"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: Height * 0.03,
                          width: Width * 0.06,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage("images/i2.png"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: Width * 0.04,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: Height * 0.03,
                          width: Width * 0.06,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage("images/i1.png"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: Width * 0.06,
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Home
                    ? Container(
                  height: Height * 0.9,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Hi, this is home page",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                    : Container(),
                bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Favorite
                    ? Container(
                  height: Height * 0.9,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Hi, this is favorite page",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                    : Container(),
                bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Search
                    ? Container(
                  height: Height * 0.9,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Hi, this is search page",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                    : Container(),
                bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Account
                    ? Container(
                  height: Height * 0.9,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Hi, this is account page",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                    : Container(),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24, bottom: 30),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        BottomBar(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Home;
                              });
                            },
                            bottomIcons:
                            bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Home ? true : false,
                            icons: EvaIcons.home,
                            text: "Home"),
                        BottomBar(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Favorite;
                              });
                            },
                            bottomIcons: bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Favorite
                                ? true
                                : false,
                            icons: EvaIcons.heartOutline,
                            text: "Favorite"),
                        BottomBar(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Search;
                              });
                            },
                            bottomIcons: bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Search
                                ? true
                                : false,
                            icons: EvaIcons.search,
                            text: "Search"),
                        BottomBar(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Account;
                              });
                            },
                            bottomIcons: bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Account
                                ? true
                                : false,
                            icons: EvaIcons.personOutline,
                            text: "Account"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )

            // Container(
            //   padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20,vertical: 15),
            //   margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30,horizontal: 20),
            //   decoration: BoxDecoration(
            //     color: Colors.white,
            //     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
            //   ),
            //   child: Row(
            //     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            //     children: [
            //       Icon(Icons.search),
            //       Text('Search pet to adopt'),
            //       Icon(Icons.settings)
            //
            //     ],
            //   ),
            // ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks . Also one question how to change the color ? Its showing something purple now.

Comment: add wrap it with Container() and set the color